# Find all documents by Id in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the documents as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bf662551a0ffc2f40c91945"
    },
    "categories": [
        "angular"
    ],
    "title": "1",
    "details": "1",
    "url": "undefined",
    "category": {
        "$oid": "5bf135657d6f2c69a527186d"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2018-11-22T08:01:25.418Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to find all documents based on category id. I tried this:

```
articleModel
    .find({category: req.params.id})
    .sort({ $natural: -1 })
    .exec(function(err, blogs) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("get blogs by category ", blogs);
      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: "blogs by category",
        blogs: blogs
      });
    });
```

but it returns empty array.

Comment: Could you post your schema code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(YOUR_ID)` when find using mongoose object ID :

```
articleModel
    .find({"category":  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)})
    .exec(function(err, blogs) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("get blogs by category ", blogs);
      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: "blogs by category",
        blogs: blogs
      });
    });
```

Comment: Its returning null

Comment: Returns an empty array

Comment: Still an empty array

Comment: Changed it to `.find({"category":  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)})` and it worked

Comment: Just update your answer with above so it will help others. Upvoted